# Retrieving data from blockchain

Tags: javascript, ethereum, truffle

I am working on a project in which I need to upload some data such as an image, text file etc to a Ethereum Blockchain and to retrieve it later using some kind of a block hash which I want to store in a Database.
Can you please suggest me how can I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use base64 string format for saving in blockchain, just google "encode base64 image javascript" ;)